# Override __init__ for all classes in module

Tags: python, django, inheritance, reflection, metaprogramming

In my Django project, I want all my model fields to have an additional argument called `documentation`. (It would be similar to `verbose_name` or `help_text`, but instead for internal documentation.)

This seems straightforward: just subclass and override the field's `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, documentation=None, **kwargs):
    self.documentation = documentation
    super(..., self).__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
```

The question is how do I make this apply to *all* of the 20-something field classes in django.db.models (`BooleanField`, `CharField`, `PositiveIntegerField`, etc.)?

The only way I see is to use metaprogramming with the inspect module:

```
import inspect
import sys
from django.db.models import *

current_module = sys.modules[__name__]

all_field_classes = [Cls for (_, Cls) in inspect.getmembers(current_module,
            lambda m: inspect.isclass(m) and issubclass(m, Field))]

for Cls in all_field_classes:
    Cls.__init__ = <???>
```

I am not used to seeing code like this, and don't even know if it will work. I wish I could just add the attribute to the base Field class, and have it inherit to all the child classes, but I don't see how that could be done.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about overwriting `Field` class?

Comment: @Raydel - it won't work unless all subclasses of it are carefully crafted to not care about arguments which are not specific to the subclass and call the `__init__` of the superclass with the unknown, extra, argument. You can design a system to behave like this, but you can't rely on others' work to do that. (Although one could look at the soruce code and see what happens)

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: Do you mean to subclass `Field` in my code? I don't think that would affect the behavior of `Field`'s subclasses, though. That would just be creating another subclass.

Comment: No - @RaydelMiranda was talking about monkeypatching the original `Field`, not subclassing it. My previous comment states why it would probably not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed - you are ont he right track.
In python, introspection is a normal thing, and and you don even need to use the  `inspect` module just because it "I am using introspection and meta programing, I must need `inspect` ) :-)

One thing that is not considered that much of a good practice, though, is Monkey patching - that is, if you change the classes as they are in the  `django.db.models` itself, so that other modules will import the modified classes from there and use the modified version. (Note that in this case: not recommended != will not work) - so you would be better creating all the new model classes in your own module, and importing them from your own module, instead of from  `django.db.models`

So, something along:

```
from django.db import models

# A decorator to implement the behavior you want for the
# __init__ method
def new_init(func):
   def __init__(self, *args,  **kw):
       self.documentation = kw.pop("documentation", None)
       return func(self, *args, **kw)

for name, obj in models.__dict__.items():
    #check if obj is a class:
    if not isinstance(obj, type):
        continue

    # creates a new_init, retrieving the original one -
    # taking care for not to pick it as an unbound method -
    # check: http://pastebin.com/t1SAusPS
    new_init_method = new_init(obj.__dict__.get("__init__", lambda s:None))

    # dynamically creates a new sublass of obj, overriding just the __init__ method:
    new_class = type(name, (obj,), {"__init__": new_init_method}) 

    # binds the new class to this module's scope:
    globals().__setitem__(name, new_class)
```

Or if you prefer using monkey patching, as it is easier :-p

```
from django.db import models

def new_init(func):
   def __init__(self, *args,  **kw):
       self.documentation = kw.pop("documentation", None)
       return func(self, *args, **kw)

for name, obj in models.__dict__.items():
    #check if obj is a class:
    if not isinstance(obj, type):
        continue

    obj.__init__ = new_init(obj.__dict__["__init__"])
```